# Dart Angular2 on Nodejs debugging

Tags: node.js, angular, dart, dart-pub

The tutorial of angular2 with dart never actually uses a real server, always pub serve.

How can I debug my dart code when using a real server like NodeJS?  Atm I'm just getting errors like a.b.Y is not defined(in the browser), which is completely useless.

Is there some kind of source mapping for dart2js?

Ok after building with pub build --mode=debug.  The dart source is available in chrome dev tools (it shows "source mapped from main.dart.js" for all my dart files.  Breakpoints are not stopping tho.

Comment: What do you want to debug, the client or the server?

Comment: If you build `pub build mode=debug` then source maps should be created.

Comment: The client.  My server is nodejs(in js) and not a problem.

Comment: You can also use a proxy that redirects calls to Dart source code to `pub build` and everything else to your nodejs server to debug Dart code (with Dartium) or JS code with any other browser.

Comment: Where are you debugging? Chrome devtools, WebStorm, ...?

Comment: in chrome devtools yes

Comment: Out of ideas here. I haven't used this since quite some time. Maybe someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the problem I had with another Dart library when I tried running in another server via NGINX. Is your `pubspec.yaml` properly set up?

My issue was that I wasn't using the `transformers` or `entry_points` section of the `pubspec.yaml` which generates definitions of start up classes.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38284430/174368

Is your `pubspec.yaml` similar to the Dart Angular2 example below?

https://angular.io/docs/dart/latest/quickstart.html#!#add-config-files

Also make sure you serve the `build` directory via `nodejs` because it'll edit your `index.html` put it in the `build` directory and add automatically other `link`/`script` lines to include other files.

This might also be part of the reason you can't see your breakpoints. That happened to me too.

Comment: yeah my pubspec is like the one in the link and my build is served.  My app works, it is just that when I have an error it is impossible to figure out where it comes from.

Comment: @DaafVader Make sure sourcemap option is turned on in chrome developer tools and that `main.dart.js.map` is generated by dart in debug mode.